# Possible to use a ClickOnce deployment from a private Azure blob storage container?

Tags: azure, clickonce, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have setup a blob storage container that is public.  I then put the ClickOnce application in that container and it works fine.  There is discussion about making the storage container private for better security.

Much of what I have read said that this is not currently possible.  Wanted to throw it out to the StackOverflow community.

Is it possible to setup a ClickOnce application to work from a private storage container.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by setting a container to private and using the URL as install point for your clickonce application will not work. Because you would need the publish URL to be accessible by the user and, a private container will not make the URL publicly accessible.

If we talk about "is it possible", it sure is technically possible. With your private container, if you use SAS (Shared access signature) and ACS services, you can make a private container accessible to certain uses for X amount of time. During the valid the URL will be accessible to specific user and after the time expire the URL will be locked as bring the private container. This sure is a complex process but to make the answer full, it sure can be done if that is must for your requirement.